# Plotting a line between 2-D point to its corresponding value in 3-D

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a dashed line in a 3-D Matplotlib plot. I would like to get a dashed line between each (`x_pt, y_pt`) to its corresponding `z_pt`.

```
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
import matplotlib
matplotlib.rcParams['mathtext.fontset'] = 'cm'
matplotlib.rcParams['axes.labelsize'] = 13

def z_function(x, y):
    a = 1
    b = 5.1/(4*np.pi**2)
    c = 5/np.pi
    r = 6
    s = 10
    t = 1/(8*np.pi)
    return a*(y - b*x**2 + c*x - r)**2 + s*(1 - t)*np.cos(x) + s

x = np.linspace(-5, 10, 100)
y = np.linspace(0, 15, 100)

indexes = np.random.randint(0, 100, 5)
x_pt = x[indexes]
y_pt = y[indexes]

z_pt = z_function(x_pt, y_pt)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.scatter(x_pt, y_pt, color='k', marker='x', depthshade=False)
ax.scatter(x_pt, y_pt, z_pt, color='k', marker='^', depthshade=False)
ax.set_xticks([-5, 0, 5, 10])
ax.set_yticks([0, 5, 10, 15])
ax.set_zticks([100, 200, 300])
ax.view_init(30, -120)
ax.set_xlabel(r'$x_1$')
ax.set_ylabel(r'$x_2$')
ax.zaxis.set_rotate_label(False) 
ax.set_zlabel(r'$f(x)$', rotation=0)
ax.w_xaxis.pane.fill = False
ax.w_yaxis.pane.fill = False
ax.w_zaxis.pane.fill = False
plt.show()
```

[image]

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you need to connect the point (x,y,0) to (x,y,z) like so:

```
for x_,y_,z_ in zip(x_pt, y_pt, z_pt):
    ax.plot([x_,x_],[y_,y_],[0,z_], '--', c='grey')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It should be as simple as:

```
ax.plot(x_pt, y_pt, zs=z_pt, color='blue', marker='--', depthshade=False)
```

alternatively using:

```
ax.plot3D(x_pt, y_pt, z_pt, marker='--')
```

UPDATE:

You will need to create extra dummy coordinates for each point on the x-y axis, like so:

```
import numpy as np
n = 10 # number of points in the line
for i in len(x_pt):
  x_range = np.linspace(0, x_pt[i], n)
  y_range = np.linspace(0, y_pt[i], n)
  ax.plot3D(x_range, y_range, [z_pt[i]]*n, marker='--')
```

NOTE: Untested

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have tried using the alternate method you mentioned. In both situations, the plot we get only connects all the z_pt. But I would like each (x_pt, y_pt) to be connected to it's corresponding z_pt.

Comment: Oh right, so for each point in the x-y axis you want a straight link going to the origin at that z-axis?

Comment: Yes. For each point in x-y axis, I want a dashed line going to the corresponding value in z-axis. For example: (x_pt[0], y_pt[0]) passed through the z_function give z_pt[0]. So I want a line from (x_pt[0], y_pt[0]) to z_pt[0]. Thanks